# How to check previous / removeddigital signature on a file

Tags: windows, signature, signed, digital

I want to verify if there is a way to check if a file **HAD** a digital signature.

Current example:

- File A.EXE -> with a valid digital signature

(I've created a copy B.EXE -> edit it in notepad and save it) - At this point the file no longer has the digital signature

My question -> is there a way / a tool / to check that B.EXE **HAD** a digital certificate in the past?

Thank you

Comment: If you change one byte for example, the file would still be signed with a certificate but it would no longer be valid so Windows will not display it.

Answer (score 0):

A [PE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) file has a certificate data directory with a non-zero RVA and size and at least one certificate entry if it has been signed.

Note: There are [tools](https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/disitool/) you can use to remove the certificate.